# How to add two digits of precision to the output of my if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to have the output of my `if` statement have two digits of precision.

I have tried using the following with no success:

`options(digits=)`

`format(round())`

`formatC()`

**Code**

```r
x <- 30
y <- 120.00

if(x %% 5 == 0 & y >= x + 0.50){
  y - x - 0.50
}else{
  y
}
#> [1] 89.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I would like the output for this, and future iterations with differing x and y values, to have two digits of precision `89.50`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `nsmall` argument in `format`.

```
x <- 30
y <- 120.00

if(x %% 5 == 0 & y >= x + 0.50){
  z <- y - x - 0.50
}else{
  z <- y
}

format(z, nsmall = 2)
#[1] "89.50"
```